# Issue with config.globalResources

Tags: aurelia

I'm new to Aurelia.

I was experimenting with different datepickers and I ran into a strange problem where the last globalResources configuration overrides the previous.

I have the following code:

Configuration:

main.js

```
export async function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .feature('components/controls');

  await aurelia.start();
  aurelia.setRoot('app');
}
```

components/controls/index.js

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources(
        './bootstrap-datepicker',        
        './jquery-datetimepicker',        
    );
}
```

Custom Attributes:

bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
...
@customAttribute('bootstrap-datepicker')
@inject(Element)
export class BootstrapDatePickerCustomAttribute {
    ...
}
```

jquery-datetimepicker

```
...
@customAttribute('jquery-datetimepicker')
@inject(Element)
export class JQueryDateTimePickerCustomAttribute {
    ...
}
```

Component:
.html

```
<template>
    ...
    <input type="text" bootstrap-datepicker value.bind='myDate'>

    ...
    <input type="text" jquery-datetimepicker value.bind='myDate2'>
</template>
```

.js

```
export class Controls {
    myDate = null;
    myDate2 = null;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

In this case both inputs will show the **jquery-datetimepicker**. If i change the **index.js** like this:

```
export function configure(config) {
    config.globalResources(
        './jquery-datetimepicker', 
        './bootstrap-datepicker',    
    );
}
```

Both inputs will show the **bootstrap-datepicker**

When I **console.log(element)** both attributes recieve the correct element, but still only one of them shows on both inputs.

What am i doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind posting your code to a github gist? Preferably a runnable one forked from here: https://gist.run/?id=c6f4ecf8f308037a92b3cee5ff40fed1

Comment: Is this exactly how your code is registering resources? From what I know, you should be passing in an array for multiple resources, not individual strings.

Comment: I tried with an array the result is the same. Creating a gist now. Thanks

Comment: @AshleyGrant I'm using the webpack skeleton and I wanted to be the same. So here is the exact code here: https://github.com/d-kostov-dev/aurelia-datepicker-examples

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This answer is invalid, as brought out in the comments, `config.globalResources()` actually accepts both an `Array` and separate strings as params. The cause of the problem is elsewhere.

**ORIGINAL**

The `config.globalResources()` method accepts an `Array`. You are giving it multiple strings instead.

Try this:

```
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources([
    './bootstrap-datepicker',
    './jquery-datetimepicker'    
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah most of the examples are wrong then. But anyway one of the things i tried is to use an Array, but the result is the same. I'm creating a gist now. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using attributes anyway? Seems like something I would use custom elements for instead. `<bootstrap-datepicker value.bind=""></bootstrap-datepicker>`

Comment: Yeah this is the next step, but i want to have access to both. :) Plus I'm learning the framework I want to try everything :)

Comment: @Travo I hope you don't mind if I correct you a bit. `globalResources()` expects an array of strings or else it fallbacks to the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments). [Source code](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/blob/master/src/framework-configuration.js#L221).
Therefore `globalResources(<string>, <string>)` definition is also valid.

Comment: Ooh, I did not know that. That's also pretty cool, I don't mind at all. Thanks!